# Error Warning al usar foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Debo consultar los datos de una table antes de cerrar la session automaticamente, esta consulta debe traer datos de la tabla "nombre_tabla" la cuál tiene el nombre del usuario que esta en la sessión actual, al hacer la consulta y ahcer un foreach me arroja un **warning**. Este es el mensaje.

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){

    $user = $_SESSION['name'];
    $consulta = "SELECT * nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$user'";
    $ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    ?>
    <?php
        foreach ($ejecucion as $datos):
         echo $datos['columna_usuario'];
    ?>

    <?php
endforeach;
    ?>
```

Comment: ¿Si colocas el `foreach` asi `foreach ($ejecucion as $datos){ echo $datos['columna_usuario'];}`, te muestra el mismo warning?

Comment: Cuál es el warning en cuestión, creo que no se te pego en la pregunta utiliza [edit] y añadelo.

Comment: He seguido tus instrucciones ahora sale este nuevo error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\selection.php on line 33

Comment: @Sergio si, me olvide de decir que con eso ya no iba a ser necesario el `endforeach;`. Saludos.

Comment: Sigue el mismo error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\selection.php on line 29. Esa linea es donde esta el foreach ($ejecucion as $datos){ echo $datos['columna_usuario'];}

Comment: `mysqli_query()` te devuelve un recurso de base de datos, no un arreglo, por eso tienes el error, en todo caso usa `while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conexion, $consulta) { echo $datos['columna_usuario']; }` para recorrer los resultados de la consulta.

Comment: Ahora sale este error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\selection.php on line 29, lo probe utiliazndo mysqli_fetch_array tambien pero sale el mismo erro.

Comment: Simplemente elimina `$conexion` de `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, y cambia `$consulta` por `$ejecucion` y ya te debe funcionar, es decir, `while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecucion)`

Comment: Aún aparecen los mismos errores: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\selection.php on line 29

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\selection.php on line 31

Comment: ¿Si haces un `echo $user`, obtienes correctamente los datos a comprobar? Intenta también ejecutar tu consulta manualmente en tu `phpMyAdmin` y así comprobar que funciona, es decir, `SELECT * nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = 'tu_usuario'`

Comment: Ahora el error es porque la consulta falló, copia y pega en _PhpMyAdmin_ para saber a qué se debe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta como te han mencionado, la función `mysqli_query` no devuelve un `array` sino retorna un `objeto`.

Segun el [**manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) `mysqli_query`:

> Retorna `FALSE` en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` o `EXPLAIN` es exitosa, `mysqli_query()` retornará un objeto `mysqli_result`. Para otras consultas exitosas de `mysqli_query()` retornará `TRUE`.

Para retornar resultados desde tus Base de Datos, usuria `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, es decir, obtener una fila de resultado como un array asociativo.

[mysqli_fecth_assco()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), devuelve un array asociativo de strings que representa a la fila obtenida del conjunto de resultados, donde cada clave del array representa el nombre de una de las columnas de éste; o NULL si no hubieran más filas en dicho conjunto de resultados.

**Ejemplo:**

```
 <?php

 if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){

    $user = $_SESSION['name'];
    //Consulta
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$user'";
    $ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    // Verdadero consulta
    if ($ejecucion):
       // Obtiene el número de filas de un resultado
       if (mysqli_num_rows($ejecucion) > 0) :
         // Obtener array asociativo
         while($datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecucion)) :   
           // Imprimos datos.
           echo $datos['columna_usuario'];
         endwhile;
       else:
         echo 'No se encontraron registros';
       endif;

       /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
       mysqli_free_result($ejecucion);

    else:
      echo 'La consulta fallo.';
    endif;

 }
 ?>
```

Sobre el error de tu comentario, debes de tener algun error en tu consulta.

> El Warning: `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` expects parameter 1, se debe a que `mysqli::query` devuelve `FALSE` en caso de que la consulta dé un error.

Si miramos tu consulta, en este caso el **fallo** está en que se te ha olvidado añadir `FROM`.

*Fallo:*
`$consulta = "SELECT * ^^^^ nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$user'";`

*Correcto:*
`$consulta = "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$user'";`

Ahora si deseas obtener el resultado como un **array** podriás hacer lo siguiente.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE columna_usuario = '$user'";
$ejecucion = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

for ($set = array (); $row = $ejecucion->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);

echo'<pre>';
print_r($set);
echo'</pre>';
```

Comment: Te he actualizado mi respuesta, el fallo de tu sentencia es qué se te olvido `FROM` en tu consulta, luego te he dejado un ejemplo alternativo al final para obtener los datos en un `array`.